# Accessing certificates pushed by MDM

Tags: ios, objective-c, mdm

I wanted to know is there a way to access certificate pushed by MDM server through your app?

Comment: What type of certificate?

Answer (score 0):

A few years later - is there still no way to access the MDM issued X.509 certificates?

I'm using this code, but getting zero results. And as far as google helps, there is also no way to see if there is any cert at all?

```
CFTypeRef   certificateRef     = NULL;                      // 1
const char *certLabelString = "XenMobile MDM";
CFStringRef certLabel = CFStringCreateWithCString(
                                                  NULL, certLabelString,
                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);         
const void *keys[] =   { kSecClass, kSecAttrLabel, kSecReturnRef };
const void *values[] = { kSecClassCertificate, certLabel, kCFBooleanTrue };
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys,
                                          values, 3,
                                          NULL, NULL);      
status = SecItemCopyMatching(dict, &certificateRef);        
if (status == errSecItemNotFound) {
    _UILabelINFO.text = @"error The item cannot be found (errSecItemNotFound) :";
    _UILabelINFO.text = [_UILabelINFO.text stringByAppendingString:(__bridge NSString *)(certLabel)];
} else {
    _UILabelINFO.text = @"retrieved keychain reference";
}
```